# TCP Sending Simple Flood Control And Sync - P2P Webcam

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, webcam

With the help of some nice people from SO I have slowly built a small P2P app that sends and receives a stream of images of about 4kb each.

On 127.0.0.1 the receive keeps up with the sending, but when I try it on a remote machine it seems to me the receiving cannot keep up, I have perhaps sent 6 images but the receiver has only received one so far... and as time passes the difference gets bigger, until you see yourself a whole minute ago on the other screen. Its worth noting I would like this to work well on a connection that is about 64kbps-100kbps in another country where the ping times might be very big like 250ms or more.

What are the synchronisation options I have?

I have been advised by my brother of a simple solution which is to implement a 1:1 send/receive. So I only send an image when I receive one.

As I am a total beginner in network programming, any other tips are most welcome, here is my complete code :

```
namespace MyPrivateChat
{
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using AForge.Video;
    using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using AForge.Imaging.Filters;

    public partial class fChat : Form
    {
        public fChat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void fChat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // get ip
            _ownExternalIp = GetPublicIP();
            Text = "My Private Chat - IP: " + _ownExternalIp;

            // get video cam
            var _videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            if (_videoDevices.Count != 0)
            {
                _videoDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(_videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
                btnStart.Enabled = true;
            }

            // fire up listener
            listeningThread.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        public string GetPublicIP()
        {
            string ip = "";
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                Match m = Regex.Match(wc.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/"), @"(?<IP>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})");
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    ip = m.Groups["IP"].Value;
                }
            }
            return ip;
        }
        private void mnuPasteOwnIP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtPartnerIP.Text = _ownExternalIp;
        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_tcpOut == null)
            {
                // tcp server setup
                _tcpOut = new TcpClient();
                _tcpOut.Connect(txtPartnerIP.Text, 54321);
                tmrLive.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                tmrLive.Enabled = false;
                _tcpOut.Client.Disconnect(true);
                _tcpOut.Close();
                _tcpOut = null;
            }

            if (!_videoDevice.IsRunning)
            {
                _videoDevice.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(NewFrameReceived);
                _videoDevice.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(640, 480);
                _videoDevice.DesiredFrameRate = 100;
                _videoDevice.Start();
                btnStart.Text = "Stop";
            }
            else
            {
                _videoDevice.SignalToStop();
                btnStart.Text = "Start";
            }
        }
        private void NewFrameReceived(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap)e.Frame.Clone();
            byte[] imgBytes = EncodeToJpeg(img, 25).ToArray();

            if (_tcpOut.Connected)
            {
                NetworkStream ns = _tcpOut.GetStream();
                if (ns.CanWrite)
                {
                    ns.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(imgBytes.Length), 0, 4);
                    ns.Write(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);
                    _totalFramesSent++;
                }
            }
        }
        private void listeningThread_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _tcpIn = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 54321);
            _tcpIn.Start();

            TcpClient _inClient = _tcpIn.AcceptTcpClient();
            lblStatus.Text = "Connected - Receiving Broadcast";
            tmrLive.Enabled = true;

            NetworkStream ns = _inClient.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                // read image size. 
                Byte[] imgSizeBytes = new Byte[4];
                int totalBytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    int bytesRead = ns.Read(imgSizeBytes, totalBytesRead, 4 - totalBytesRead);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break; // problem
                    }
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                } while (totalBytesRead < 4);

                // read image
                int imgSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(imgSizeBytes, 0);
                Byte[] imgBytes = new Byte[imgSize];
                totalBytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    int bytesRead = ns.Read(imgBytes, totalBytesRead, imgSize - totalBytesRead);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break; // problem
                    }
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                } while (totalBytesRead < imgSize);

                picVideo.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imgBytes));
                _totalFramesReceived++;
            }
        }
        private void CloseVideoDevice()
        {
            if (_videoDevice != null)
            {
                if (_videoDevice.IsRunning)
                {
                    _videoDevice.SignalToStop();
                }
                _videoDevice = null;
            }
        }
        private void fChat_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            CloseVideoDevice();
        }
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
        private void tmrLive_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _totalSecondsLive++;
            lblStats.Text = "S:"+_totalFramesSent + " R:" + _totalFramesReceived + " T:"+ _totalSecondsLive;
            if (_totalSecondsLive == 60)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Total Frames : " + _totalFramesSent);
            }
        }

        #region ENCODING JPEG

        private MemoryStream EncodeToJpeg(Bitmap img, long quality)
        {
            using (EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1))
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
                img.Save(ms, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), myEncoderParameters);
                return ms;
            }
        }
        private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion

        VideoCaptureDevice _videoDevice;
        TcpClient _tcpOut;
        TcpListener _tcpIn;
        string _ownExternalIp;
        int _totalFramesSent;
        int _totalFramesReceived;
        int _totalSecondsLive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not a TCP specific problem. You are producing faster that you are consuming. Therefore you need to throttle your producer.

I would change the producer to wait for an acknowledgement from the consumer before I send the next image. I would discard all new images in the meantime.

On the producer you would keep a status flag which allows you to track if a frame has been sent *and* it has not been acknowledged. While this flag is true you discard new images as they appear. When it is false you send an image and set it to true. When the acknowledgement comes you set the flag to false.

Edit: I would implement the acknowledgement as a "bool" (a byte on the network) because this will acknowledge much faster than sending an image as a response. I would define two "messages": MessageType.Image and MessageType.Acknowledgement. The receiver can then see which MessageType arrived and either update the screen or start sending the next image.

Edit 2: You do not need to just discard images. You can have a variable `Image latestUnsentImage`. When the cam produces an image you unconditionally overwrite this variable. When you need to send an image you just access this variable. This will send always the latest available and unsent image.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I have been suggested. This "acknowledgement" would it better as a small boolean value or is it better to await an image from the opposite direction as acknowledgement?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, they are simple and within my reach. And hopefully effective also when combined with variable jpeg compression suggested by Eugen Rieck above.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here, is that you fill up the buffers on the sending machine by generating data to send much faster, than it can be sent over the network. My approach would be

- create two boolean flags newImageAvailable and readyToSend on the class level, both starting at false
- In NewFrameReceived create a new image, but don't yet send it. Atomically store the byte[] in a class vairable instead and set newImageAvailable to true, then call new function TrySendImage() (see below for info)
- On Tcp connect set readyToSend to true and call TrySendImage()
- In TrySendImage()
- .... check if BOTH newImageAvailable and readyToSend are true, if not do
  nothing
- .... set newImageAvailable and readyToSend to false
- .... Send image (Size + data) asynchronously (BeginSend())
- In the completion notification for BeginSend() set readyToSend to true

While this is a bit complicated, it makes sure, that allways the newest image is sent, and only if the image before is "on the wire".

I consider this superior to a "1:1 send/receive" solution, as you often have cases, where bandwidth is different in the two directions - in this case the 1:1 solution would degrade performance of the good direction to performance of the bad direction.

An optimization I have used on a similar project is, to dynamically adapt the quality parameter of the JPEG encoding: If framerate falls below a threshold reduce quality by a factor, until a minimum is reached, if framerate climbs above another threshold increase quality by a factor, again until a mmaximum.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your solutions seems superior but its a bit more complex than what I am comfortable with at this stage, I will try it once I get a simple solution working. I love the jpeg variable compression idea. Btw would changing the bitdepth affect the size much, its at 24bit right now, 16bit more appropriate for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well as for what "usr" has said about throttling, instead of discarding your images, you might want to add these captured images to a queue. From te queue you should be able to pick them up one by one and via another thread and transport them over the network. You might even add a sequence number to the images being transported apart from the boolean acknowledgement to ensure a transport of images. Anything that is not transported should be enqueued again. Sequencing should allow you to sort the correct order of images and produce a lesser loss of data.

Sender

- create sequence number
- assign bool flag
- Enqueue in transport queue
- Dequeue and transport (separate thread)
- Re queue if no acknowledgement

Receiver (possibly what you can do)

- Receive from network
- Send acknowledgement
- Check sequence number and sort  (may be storage required to sequence 
  numbering check)

Comment: A queue will not work as the network will never catch up. Thoughput is limited.

Comment: |You might be right...but I though of lesser data loss as well.